# The micronaut bean injection is not working correctly after creating new beans unless gradle build is made with --rerun-tasks

Tags: kotlin, gradle, dependency-injection, build.gradle, micronaut

After using micronaut-inject for dependency injection if new bean is created we have to use --rerun-tasks flag in order for kapt to work otherwise its not injecting newly created beans
seems gradle cache issue
What can be the possible solution or configuration that might be missing

Comment: Does it work if you use `-t`?

Comment: Which version of Micronaut?

Comment: version 2.2.3 , it seems because of gradle cache , new beans are not generated but rather gradle cache is used instead